# WebStorm tries to open Chrome for debugging

Tags: javascript, debugging, webstorm

I created a new JavaScript Debug configuration. Firefox is the first browser in the list and the default browser is set to **system default** which is Firefox too. I've also tried to use **first in list** as default which also is Firefox. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and WebStorm 2016.1.1.

When I now trigger the debugging via the little bug icon I get the following error message:

> "Cannot run program "google-chrome": error=2, No such file or directory"

I thought okay, might be a bug. I removed all browsers but Firefox from the WebStorm settings and tried again. Didn't work, all the default browsers just reappeared after a restart of the IDE and the error from above kept popping up.

Any advice to force WebStorm to use Firefox?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaScript debugger in WebStorm works only with Google Chrome browser together with JetBrains IDE Support extension.

Comment: just to expand a little: if you want to open firefox after launching, you need to uncheck the option "with javascript debugger" in the run/debug configurations.